# Ruby, cucumber, capybaras: is it possible to switch between sauce labs and local runs when running parallel tests?

Tags: ruby, selenium

Currently I am working on an environment that should be able to run both locally and on sauce labs but I have the following issue:

When using Cucumber the tag "@selenium" is needed for the sauce integration with parallel tests. However this tag also forces the test to run on sauce labs (I want to be able to switch between sauce and local). Is there a way I can use an environment variable or tag to change this behavior?

OS: OSX Yosemite
Testing Stack: Ruby, Capybara, Cucumber, Rake.

Note: Without the Selenium tag I can run both sauce labs and local for a single test run or sequential all test run. I am new to ruby/capybara/cucumber so any general tips greatly appreciated)

Approach that works with a single feature and the cucumber feature:

```
if (ENV["RUN_ON_SAUCE"] == "true")
  puts('TRUE: ENV["RUN_ON_SAUCE"] = ' + ENV["RUN_ON_SAUCE"])
  Capybara.default_driver = :sauce
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :sauce
else
  puts('FALSE: ENV["RUN_ON_SAUCE"] = ' + ENV["RUN_ON_SAUCE"])
  Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for me. I'm using cucumber with capybara and my features are marked with @selenium and couple of other tags(@core) which I use for filtering.

Command to execute the suite on sauce labs-

> RUN_ON_SAUCE=true
>   SC_EXECUTABLE=path/to/sauce/connect/executable 
>   START_TUNNEL=true ENVIRONMENT=staging parallel_cucumber features -o
>   "-t @core" -n 8

Command to execute the suite locally-

> parallel_cucumber features -o
>   "-t @core" -n 8

```
if ENV['HEADLESS']
  require 'capybara/poltergeist'
  Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
  Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {:debug => false, :default_wait_time => 60, :timeout => 120, :js_errors => false, :window_size => [1024, 768]})
  end
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist

elsif ENV['RUN_ON_SAUCE']
  require 'sauce'
  require 'sauce/capybara'
  require 'sauce/cucumber'
  Capybara.default_driver = :sauce
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :sauce
  Sauce.config do |c|
    if ENV['START_TUNNEL']
      c[:start_tunnel] = ENV['START_TUNNEL']
      c[:sauce_connect_4_executable] = ENV['SC_EXECUTABLE']
      c[:connect_options] = {tunnel_domains: "'*.example.com'", max_logsize: "10485760"}
    end
    c[:browsers] = [
        ["Windows 8", "Internet Explorer", "10"],
        ["Windows 10", "Internet Explorer", "11"],
        ["Windows XP", "Internet Explorer", "8"]
    ]
    c[:'max-duration'] = 300
  end
else
  Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
  Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 120
  Capybara.page.driver.browser.manage.window.maximize
end
```